# The field 'usernameCanonical' is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am using `FOSUserBundle` in my Symfony 2.7 project. In the `composer.json` file the requirement is defined as `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev"`. Currently version/commit **45d6f40** (11/03/2015) is installed.

After using `composer update` the latest version **7abb0ff** was installed. After this, I get the following exception when trying to create new users:

> The field 'usernameCanonical' is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness

Searching for solution for this problem brought up older issues dealing with the same exception ([here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1565) and [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1638)). However I was not able to solve the problem with the solution discussed in these issues.

[Issue 1565](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1565) proposes to use `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;` instead of `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;`. But this solution seems not to be valid for version 2.x. The 2.x documentation says that you should extend from `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`, which makes sense since there are no `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\...` classes anymore.

My User class looks like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * This class represents the User entity and extends the FOSBundle base user
 * Entity class to be able to use FOSUserBundle to manage the application users.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_user") * 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    ...
}
```

In [Issue 1638](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1638) the solution was to use `auto_mapping` in the Doctrine configuration. I already did this.

So neither of the existing solutions worked for my. Additional all existing issues to this problem are quite old.

Of course I could simply downgrade back to version/commit 45d6f40. However I would prefer to solve the problem instead of ignoring it :-)

**Any other idea how I can solve this?**

PS: This is my `composer show -i` output:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.7             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.6.0             Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0             Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.6.1             Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.4.5             Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.2.0             Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1             Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5              A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1             Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.8             Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
friendsofsymfony/http-cache          1.4.0              Tools to manage cache invalidation
friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle   1.3.4              Set path based HTTP cache headers and send invalidation requests to your HTTP cache
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle         1.4.2              This Bundle provides various tools to rapidly develop RESTful API's with Symfony2
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle         dev-master 7abb0ff Symfony FOSUserBundle
gremo/buzz-bundle                    v1.1.0             Symfony Bundle for using the lightweight Buzz HTTP client.
guzzle/guzzle                        v3.9.3             PHP HTTP client. This library is deprecated in favor of https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17            a PHP SQL highlighting library
jms/metadata                         1.5.1              Class/method/property metadata management in PHP
jms/parser-lib                       1.0.0              A library for easily creating recursive-descent parsers.
jms/serializer                       1.3.1              Library for (de-)serializing data of any complexity; supports XML, JSON, and YAML.
jms/serializer-bundle                1.1.0              Allows you to easily serialize, and deserialize data of any complexity
kriswallsmith/assetic                v1.3.2             Asset Management for PHP
kriswallsmith/buzz                   v0.15              Lightweight HTTP client
leafo/scssphp                        v0.6.6             scssphp is a compiler for SCSS written in PHP.
moontoast/math                       1.1.0              A mathematics library, providing functionality for large numbers
paragonie/random_compat              v2.0.2             PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phpcollection/phpcollection          0.5.0              General-Purpose Collection Library for PHP
phpoption/phpoption                  1.5.0              Option Type for PHP
psr/log                              1.0.0              Common interface for logging libraries
sensio/distribution-bundle           v2.3.22            The base bundle for the Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v2.3.4             This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle              v2.3.5             This bundle generates code for you
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.4.3             Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/assetic-bundle               v2.7.1             Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.8.2             Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.11            Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                      v2.7.7             The Symfony PHP framework
tfox/mpdf-port-bundle                1.3.1              A wrapper for mPDF class which allows to use mPDF in Symfony2 projects
twig/extensions                      v1.0.1             Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                            v1.25.0            Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator  v1.1.0             JSONP callback validator.
willdurand/negotiation               1.5.0              Content Negotiation tools for PHP provided as a standalone library.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solve someone problems when you get the error

> The field 'usernameCanonical' is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness

One cause is using FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser and running doctrine schema:update, if you did this you create a table on a database without several columns like username, usernameCanonical, password, etc.

When you want to access to any functionalities of this you get that message.

How to fix:

1. Dropping table fos_user on database
2. Change `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser`
   to
   `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser`
3. Run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`